# JavaScript If string is equal to anything else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How do I check if a string is not equal to any of the other options? I know I can just do a simple `else` statement, but I'm not sure if it'll work since the code in my `if`s aren't combined, yet they are just `if()` and `else if()` for its own, but then no `else`. How could I do a else statement/check if its anything else without using a `switch/case` statement?

Here's an example.

```
if(object1 === "string")  {
  function1();
}
if(object1 === "string2")  {
  function2();
if(object2 === "string" && variable === 10)  {
  function1();
}
if(object1 || object2 === "")  {
  alert("That's not a valid option!");
}
```

## WARNING

I can't insert the code here as **standalone** *or* **snippet**, due to it exceeding the maximum character limit. I am only able to add a JSFIDDLE. Please excuse the inconvienence.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheGamingHideout/cgvshLmL/)

Comment: Well why not just use a `switch` statement?

Comment: Uh, there is no reason to post your _entire game_ in the fiddle. http://sscce.org/

Comment: If the options are mutually exclusive, just use `else if` and `else` (or a `switch`.) Are you saying the options are _not_ mutually exclusive?

Comment: @Mathletics If the HTML and CSS isn't there, there would be no point troubleshooting because the JavaScript would break.

Comment: Click on the link for a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/). You don't need to post all the JS from your game either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main ways you can do it without if/else if/else being combined are a simple fall through

```
function foo(opt) {
    if (opt === 'this') { return true; }
    if (opt === 'that') { return 'something else'; }
    /* Code here represents the case that opt is not this or that */
 }
```

Another more complex way of doing it would be to have some kind of array of options and then checking them all but it's a bad pattern and you really should consider using if/else if/else as a combined tree (not sure you've really explained why you can't do this.

```
function foo(opt) {
    var checked = ['this', 'that'];
    if (opt === 'this') { return true; }
    if (opt === 'that') { return 'something else'; }
    if (checked.indexOf(opt) === -1) { return 'fall through case'; }
}
```

A switch is also possible but that's just a variation of a combined if/else if/else so if you can't use the latter I don't see how the former would help

Again the above is a **bad pattern** but if for some reason that's what you have to then there's an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to raise flags when going through one of the if statement, so that at the end, you can check those flags and if none are true, then you can do whatever you want.

```
var flag = false;
if(object1 === "string")  {
  function1();
  flag = true;
}
if(object1 === "string2")  {
  function2();
  flag = true;
if(object2 === "string" && variable === 10)  {
  function1();
  flag = true;
}
if(object1 || object2 === "")  {
  alert("That's not a valid option!");
  flag = true;
}

if(!flag) {
  alert('no other options were validated');
}
```